# Changing the display of the themename_posted_on() function

Tags: single

At present, this is what the `pl_dev_posted_on()` function is displaying:

[image: pl_dev_posted_on()]

Where can I find this function to be able to edit what it displays?

Comment: That should be in your functions.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is entirely Theme-dependent. The function will be defined in `functions.php`, or in a file included in `functions.php`.

Based on the function name, I'm going to take a guess that the Theme in question is derived from Underscores, in which case the function will be defined in `/inc/template-tags.php`.